# Jump to cross-reference inside lyx-document?

Tags: lyx

Is there a way to jump to a cross-reference inside a lyx-document?

example: click on an equation reference, say [eq:some_equation], to jump to the referenced equation?

Comment: Right-click and select "Go to label".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click and select "Go to label".